# Integer variable to Integer Collection Class?

Tags: java

I have a variable called `dice1`.

```
int dice1 = ran.nextInt(6);
```

But I would like to try to store my variables in a Collection class instead,and also be able to set them to a random Integer. How do I do that?

Comment: show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: int dice = ran.nextInt(6);

Comment: Why do u want to store your variables in a Collection? We need more information.

Comment: Marco: That's a question you should ask my teacher. Lol. I think he just wants us to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     numbers.add(ran.nextInt(6));
}
```